# how to deploy docker-compose like this to web

Tags: java, docker, deployment, docker-compose, dockerfile

i have two `war` files and i run them fine on my local computer with `docker-compose up` command. I tried deploy it with `docker-machine` tutorial: 
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/
but i got an error after `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-deploy.yml app` saying: `"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist"`
I'am not sure how to handle it - and i'm preety sure that this error is caused by `CMD ["/bin/sh","/data/app/bootstrap.sh"]` from my `Dockerfiles`.
I dont want to deploy it as two seperate `war` files to tomcat.

Bellow i give you all details of my project regarding deployment. I changed my username to `username`:

`docker-compose-deploy.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  app2:
    image: userName/dockerdocker_app2
    container_name: app2
    build:
      context: ./app2
    volumes:
      - .:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
  app:
    image: userName/dockerdocker_app
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./app
    volumes:
      - .:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
```

My `docker-compose.yml` does not have `image` lines.

Also i have two folders: `app` and `app2`

in the folder `app` i have:
`app.war`, `app2.war`, `bootstrap.sh`, `Dockerfile`

`bootstrap.sh`
is taking one of the war file and it places it in Tomcat

```
#!/bin/bash

WAR_FILE=app.war

cp /data/util/wait-for.sh /
chmod +x /wait-for.sh

echo "Starting application..."
rm -rf /opt/tomcat/webapps/*
ln -s /data/app/$WAR_FILE /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
rm -rf /opt/tomcat/logs
ln -s /data/logs/app /opt/tomcat

echo "Starting Tomcat..."

echo "org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.level = SEVERE" >> /opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.language=pl -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -D"

${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh run
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jeanblanchard/tomcat:8

ENV authType ""
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

CMD ["/bin/sh","/data/app/bootstrap.sh"]
```

in the folder `app2` i have:
 `bootstrap.sh`, `Dockerfile`

The first file only differs in this line:
`WAR_FILE=app2.war`

The second file is the same expect `CMD ["/bin/sh","/data/app2/bootstrap.sh"]`

My application runs fine with `docker-compose up` command.

But i find it difficult to deploy for example to docker-cloud.

**EDIT**

When i run `docker images -a` i have images `username/dockerdocker_app2:latest`
and `username/dockerdocker_app:latest` but after `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-deploy.yml app` with version `Named volume containers` you suggested i get

```
Updating service app_app (id: pn6ofp4vocs0fy6j6f67dc8wr)
image username/dockerdocker_app:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access username/dockerdocker_app:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

And after that when i run again `docker images -a` i do not see any image - weird ?

`docker stack ps app --no-trunc` command gives me error:

```
No such image: username/dockerdocker_app:latest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying to `docker stack` you should not use something like below

```
volumes:
      - .:/data
```

Because `docker` will need the current folder path to exists on all the nodes where the container gets instantiated. Also docker stack will not create the folder when the it doesn't exists. This is unlike `docker-compose` when running locally on docker.

So you need to use a path which exists on the node where the container gets deployed. Read the below for more details

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#add-bind-mounts-volumes-or-memory-filesystems

> type=bind: src is required, and specifies an absolute path to the file or directory to bind-mount (for example, src=/path/on/host/). **An error is produced if the file or directory does not exist.**

So you should be using either a path that already exists on your nodes. So you would use something like below

```
version: "3"
services:
  app2:
    image: userName/dockerdocker_app2
    container_name: app2
    build:
      context: ./app2
    volumes:
      - /opt/data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
  app:
    image: userName/dockerdocker_app
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./app
    volumes:
      - /opt/data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
```

And make sure each node has the `/opt/data` folder present already.

**Named volume containers**

Or you could use a named volume container which will be automatically created by swarm if it doesn't already exists

```
version: "3"
services:
  app2:
    image: userName/dockerdocker_app2
    container_name: app2
    build:
      context: ./app2
    volumes:
      - app2data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
  app:
    image: userName/dockerdocker_app
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./app
    volumes:
      - app1data:/data
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LOG-FILES-PATH=/opt/tomcat/logs
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
volumes:
  app1data:
  app2data:
```

Comment: @Taurun can you make example how it should look like ? I get it that `data` folder does not exist on stack - but how can i change my `deploy` file and other files to make it work ?

Comment: Yes, I am updating the answer with more details

Comment: @Taurun if possible i would like to have version that runs fine locally and also have other file like in question `docker-compose-deploy.yml` to deploy

Comment: The named volume one will work both locally and on swarm docker stack as well

Comment: @Taurun i think that i have to change Dockerfile as well - but i;m not sure if change to `CMD ["/bin/sh","/newPath/app2/bootstrap.sh"]` will be enough ?? Does i have to `mount` that script somehow ?

Also i have to change all `data` to `newPath` in `bootstrap.sh` or something more??
I think that i will try your proposition in the evening.

Comment: No you don't need to change anything inside dockerfile. The mount is related to where data gets saved for the changes made inside the docker container. So you need not worry about anything else. All should work, if it works locally with named containers

Comment: @Taurun i moved step forwared but i have weird issue - i edited my post  at the end. Can you look at it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167745/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-yami).